# Finding partial matches in a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list of lists and I need to find and print the list that contains full and partial matches using two conditions ignoring case.

```
l = [['2014','127.0.0.1','127','DNS sever Misconfiguration'],['2014','192.168.1.25','529','Failed logon for user user1'],['2014','127.0.0.1','1','This is a test message']]
```

Condition 1 and 2 can be anything, i.e. '192.186.1.25' or 'failed'

```
>>> for i in l:
        if 'condition 1' in i and 'condition2' in i:
           print i
```

gives  ... nothing

I can use only one condition that has exact matching and get a result

```
>>> for i in l:
      if '127.0.0.1' in i:
        print i


['2014', '127.0.0.1', '127', 'DNS sever Misconfiguration']
['2014', '127.0.0.1', '1', 'This is a test message']
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is, you're just not matching the second condition properly e.g. if you do something like this:

```
'127.0.0.1' in i and 'Misconfiguration' in i
```

but `i` looks like:

```
['2014', '127.0.0.1', '127', 'DNS sever Misconfiguration']
```

then `'127.0.0.1'` will be in `i`, but `'Misconfiguration'` won't - because it's a list, and `in` for lists is exact match, but what you're looking for is a substring of an element of `i`. If these are consistent, you can do something like:

```
'127.0.0.1' in i and 'Misconfiguration' in i[3]
```

or if they aren't, and you have to substring check all entries:

```
'127.0.0.1' in i and any('Misconfiguration' in x for x in i)
```

should do it. That will substring check each item in `i` for your search term.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 'condition' in i[3] works, but the any() would not find the second condition.

Comment: what's the second condition? this worked: `i = ['2014', '127.0.0.1', '127', 'DNS sever Misconfiguration']`, `'127.0.0.1' in i and any('Misconfiguration' in x for x in i)` -> `True`

Answer (score 1):

```
'condition 1' in i
```

will search for the *string literal* `'condition 1'`. Instead, I think you mean to search for the object referenced by the *name* `condition1`, i.e.:

```
condition1 in l
```

If you want "partial" matches, use `or`:

```
if condition1 in l or condition2 in l:
```

or `any()`:

```
if any(cond in l for cond in (condition1, condition2)):
```

Comment: Thanks, the any() condition found the correct list, but only for exact matching.  Is there a way to match any partials, like '192' would pick up the string 192.168.1.25?

Comment: Nest `any`: `if any(any(cond in li for cond in (...)) for li in l):`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt:

```
l = [['2014','127.0.0.1','127','DNS sever Misconfiguration'],    ['2014','192.168.1.25','529','Failed logon for user user1'],['2014','127.0.0.1','1','This is a test message']]

condition1 = 'Failed'
condition2 = '2014'

for lst in l:
    found_cond1 = False
    found_cond2 = False
    for string in lst:
        if condition1 in string:
            found_cond1 = True
        if condition2 in string:
            found_cond2 = True
        if found_cond1 and found_cond2:
            print(lst)
            break
```

gives

```
['2014', '192.168.1.25', '529', 'Failed logon for user user1']
```